# Scope for multiple filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and I'm using Google Translate to post.

I currently have this filter, however, it filters only one item from `public_sphere`, how do I make it a multiple filter, in this case, the user can select more than one option from `public_sphere`.

```
        scope :filter_public_sphere, -> (params) {
          params[:public_sphere].present? ?
            where(
              "public_sphere = ?", 
              AtaPublic.public_spheres[params[:public_sphere]]
            )
          :
            all
        }
```

In this case, the API must receive an array instead of a value. For that, what would my filter look like?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: database is Postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Arel** should do the work for you. If you have a `where` clause in the form `where(attribute: [array of attribute values])` it will generate an IN clause for the SQL

```
scope :filter_public_sphere, -> (params) {
  params[:public_sphere].present? ?
    where(
      public_sphere: AtaPublic.public_spheres[params[:public_sphere]]
    )
  :
    all
}
```

Assuming `AtaPublic.public_spheres[params[:public_sphere]]` returns an array of  "public_sphere" identifiers.